# Как установить драйвера на видеокарту intel в ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, видео, intel

Добрый день!

Есть неттоп 3q Shell с ubuntu 12.04 
Видеокарта intell

я не могу поменять разрешение екрана. Насколько я понял, проблема в драйвере на видео.

```
user@template:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

Пробовал поменять разрешение через xrandr:
выдает ошибку "Failed to get size of gamma for output default" и один вариант разрешения

```
user@template:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768        0.0*
```

Пробовал инсталить драйвера:

```
apt-get install mesa-utils
apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg-lts-preciese
```

Еще пробовал

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

При попытке добавить новое разрешение выдает ошибку

```
user@template:~$ cvt 1600 900 60
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
user@template:~$ xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

Пробовал установить intel-graphics-installe. Делал все по инструкцие с офф сайта, но так ничего и не получилось, как я понял, intel уже не поддерживает установку на ubuntu 12.04.

Есть идеи, как можно засетапить драйвер, или, как минимум поменять разрешение на более корректное??

Comment: лучший путь — обновить дистрибутив до [поддерживаемой разработчиками дистрибутива версии](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). и добрый практический совет: в операционной системе *gnu/linux* лучше никогда не пытаться «устанавливать» какие-либо «драйвера с сайта производителя». это не *ms/windows*, это совсем другая операционная система.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ух, ну вы даете, убанта 12 еще норм до 2017 года как я помню.
А так вам требуются не такие пакеты как

`apt-get install mesa-utils
apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg-lts-preciese`

Они у вас уже есть, не хватает проприетарных дров.

Добавляем репозиторий `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

Обновляем пакеты `sudo apt-get update`
Устанавливаем `sudo apt-get upgrade`
И `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Не помогло? Качаем вручную, заходим на https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads?keys=&download_type=11&download_version=All
Скачиваем нужные вам пакеты под версию вашего ядра! А значит листаем на странички 2-3 пока не найдем новые под наше ядро(Как узнать под какое ядро идут те или другие пакеты вводим в консоль uname -r , мне выдало 3.16.0-38-generic значит и Linux Kernel пакета который вы качаете должен быть версий 3.16, Linux Kernelего качать не требуется, раз пакет под ядро 3.16 то и ваше ядро должно быть таким), отбираем пакеты а дальше думаю разберетесь с помощью sh пакетиков.

И не слушайте людей которые говорят обновить дистрибутив, это никогда не решало проблем)